# Regex in javascript fails every other time with identical input

Tags: javascript, regex

A simple test script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reg = new RegExp('#([a-f0-9]{3})$', 'gi');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(reg.exec('#fff'));
    }
</script>
```

Console output:

```
["#fff", "fff"]
null
["#fff", "fff"]
null
["#fff", "fff"]
null
["#fff", "fff"]
null
["#fff", "fff"]
null
```

**Why is every other result null when the input remains constant?**

Comment: $ anchors the pattern to the end of the line. Without that, something like `#fff blah blah blah` would also match. Of course, at it stands now, the regex will match `blah blah blah #fff`, since it's not anchored to the start of the line with a `^`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you use the global flag, the regex becomes "sticky." That is to say, it uses a counter variable to track *where* the last match was found. Rather than matching from the beginning each time, a sticky regex will actually pick up where the last match ended. This counter will only reset back to 0 (the beginning) if the entire match fails (which is why it works every-other-time)

In your case, my suggestion would be to drop the `g` flag.

For more information: [RegExp @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp)

Comment: I did not know that... you live and learn :D

Answer (score 9):

**[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950463/regex-in-javascript-fails-every-other-time-with-identical-input/4950498#4950498)** has answered why. I just wanted to add that you can see this by checking the value of `lastIndex` on the `RegExp` object before and after the `exec` call

```
var reg = new RegExp('#([a-f0-9]{3})$', 'gi');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(reg.lastIndex);
    console.log(reg.exec('#fff'));
    console.log(reg.lastIndex);
}
```

output is

```
0
["#fff", "fff"]
4

4
null
0

0
["#fff", "fff"]
4

4
null
0

0
["#fff", "fff"]
4

4
null
0

0
["#fff", "fff"]
4

4
null
0

0
["#fff", "fff"]
4

4
null
0

undefined
```

demonstrating that on every other iteration of the loop, the regex matching is starting from where the `lastIndex` finished. You could set `lastIndex` to 0 before each `exec` call or drop the flag altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `"gi"` in the second argument, I just removed it and tested on the Chrome console:

```
var reg = new RegExp('#([a-f0-9]{3})$');
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the web...

> *Calling the **exec()** function also changes the `lastIndex` property of the **RegExp** object.* 
>   *It stores the index in the subject string at which the next match attempt will begin.*
>   *You can modify this value to change the starting position of the
>   next call to **exec()**.*

The behavior you describe indicates that the `RegExp` object has a state that is modified by calling the **exec()** method.

I think you need to modify the `lastindex` property before you re-run the exec method.
read more here: [Javascript Regexp Object](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)